# ngCordova installing instructions

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new for coding and start to work with ioinicframework...

Trying to figure out how to customize the 'splash screen' and trying to setup ngCordova. (using this link: http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/splash-screen/)

Where exactly should I inject this line?

> Inject as an Angular dependency
>
> Then, include ngCordova as a dependency in your angular module:
>
> ```
> angular.module('myApp', ['ngCordova'])"
> ```

Comment: hi.. i have the same question.. did you figured it out??

Comment: I mentioned steps in answer in below post
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37523038/adding-google-plus-login-to-ionic-app/37525072#37525072](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37523038/adding-google-plus-login-to-ionic-app/37525072#37525072)

Answer (score 0):

The line should be present in your declaring application js file. To better understand this, you should read about how angular works and how it defines modules: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module .

An angular js app has a main module defined, and it's second argument is a list of dependencies it requires. The installation instructions state that you need to add to that list ngCordova.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic Application has www/js folder.

You can include it in app.js

Answer (score -1):

You will also need to declare it as a dependency of your AngularJS app:

```
var app = angular.module('yourAppAName', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
```

Comment: Which file this line should go?