# Adding google plus login to ionic app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am trying to add google plus login to my `ionic app`.
Following this link gives me an error.

https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/google-plus-login-with-ionic-framework

Error is  : `cannot read property googleplus of undefined.`

Here is my `app.js`:

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
   $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
    cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

}
if (window.StatusBar) {
  // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
}
});
})
```

Comment: you need to show us where you are using your googleplus plugin, not your app.js

Comment: I am not sure about ionic2 but here are some sample working example for ionic 1 https://github.com/ionicthemes/google-login-with-ionic-framework and https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/google-plus-login-with-ionic-framework

Comment: registerCtrl.googleSignIn = function() {
    

    window.plugins.googleplus.login(
      {},
      function (user_data) {
        // For the purpose of this example I will store user data on local storage
        UserService.setUser({
          userID: user_data.userId,
          name: user_data.displayName,
          email: user_data.email,
          picture: user_data.imageUrl,
          accessToken: user_data.accessToken,
          idToken: user_data.idToken
        });
      },
      function (msg) {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
      }
    );
  };

Comment: <button class="btn-margin-left button button-assertive" ng-click="registerCtrl.googleSignIn()">
                <i class="ion-social-googleplus icon-size1"></i>
            </button>

Comment: i am getting an error invalid request in iphone 5s ...invalid parameter value for request uri...my javascript origin is http://localhost and my redirect uri is http://localhost/callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps to Configure authentication in Device(android)

1. `ionic start newApp`
2. `ionic platform add android`
3. `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`
4. `bower install ngCordova`
5. `bower install ng-cordova-oauth -S`
6. include both script into `index.html` above `cordova.js`

   ```
   <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
   <script src="lib/ng-cordova-oauth/dist/ng-cordova-oauth.js"></script>
   <script src="cordova.js"></script>
   ```
7. Dependency injection
8. include below code

   ```
   $scope.googleLogin = function() {
   console.log('In My Method');
   $cordovaOauth.google("Client ID", ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/urlshortener", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"]).then(function(result) {
       console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
       // results
   }, function(error) {
       // error
       console.log('In Error');
       console.log(error);
   });
   }
   ```
9. add button to view file and call the function

Comment: i have my client id for the app.. is that only api key ?

Comment: Clien Auth API Key which can be generate from google credential section.

Comment: and i didnt got your step 7

Comment: hope u inject dependancy angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'ngCordovaOauth'])
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaOauth, $q, $http) {

Comment: step 7 mean add 'ngCordova  and ngCordovaOath' in app  angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'ngCordovaOauth'])
add $cordivaOauth in controller 
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaOauth, $q, $http) {

Comment: i am getting nothing in response

Comment: menuCtrl.googleLogin = function() {
        $cordovaOauth.google("AIzaSyAW4Ou9tIE_rmeKMxashLb0B0BRXYnJ2V0", ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/urlshortener", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"]).then(function(result) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

            // results
        }, function(error) {
            // error
        });
    }

Comment: <button class="btn-margin-left button button-assertive" ng-click="menuCtrl.googleLogin()">
                <i class="ion-social-googleplus icon-size1"></i>
            </button>

Comment: <!-- ngCordova -->
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ng-cordova-oauth/dist/ng-cordova-oauth.js"></script>

Comment: i had generated browser key ..is that ok ?

Comment: once again check step 6 and rearrange scripts. after than see console log.

Comment: No.You must have to create oAuth Cliend ID. It will ask to different option in which you have to select web Application. it will generate cliend ID. so API KEY in my Code is Cliend ID.

Comment: okay i tried putting client id instead of api key ..it doesnt work

Comment: button should have only method name <a class="google-sign-in button button-block" ng-click="googleSignIn()">Sign in with Google</a>
and controller method start with
$scope.googleLogin = function() {
I didn't get your "menuCtrl".

Comment: I updated some code for you , use it so that you can get that my method is working than next step to call goole  oauth  plugin method

Comment: that is okay i tried console.log in my function i can see the content. menuctrl is just to let know in which controller we have to refer.

Comment: use ionic serve and let me know the error on console.

Comment: menuCtrl.googleLogin = function() {
            console.log('here');
            $cordovaOauth.google("myclientid", ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/urlshortener", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"]).then(function(result) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

                // results
            }, function(error) {
                // error
            });
        }

Comment: i can only see "here" on my console.

Comment: havn't you got "Cannot authenticate via a web browser"? check skype.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37569241/adding-facebook-login-to-ionic-app please check this and let me know where i am going wrong

Comment: i am getting an error invalid request in iphone 5s ...invalid parameter value for request uri...my javascript origin is http://localhost and my redirect uri is http://localhost/callback

Comment: how can i get user bday and gender ?

Comment: https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/google-plus-login-with-ionic-framework followed this tutorial worked well on andriod but not on ios, unable to get bday and gender from google api

Comment: Add as much scope as u can
$cordovaOauth.google(GOOGLE_API_KEY, ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.read",
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.write",    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.read",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profiles.read",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
]).then(function(result) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

Answer (score 2):

1 first add inappbrower in your app

2 create app id for google console
  https://console.developers.google.com

a:  create new project

b:  click on Credentials

c:  choose web application

d:  set redirect path
    if u have if not than set http://localhost/callback

e:  click on create button
 than a pop up appear save those id
after that add following code

NOTE:Please change your app id and secret id in code

```js
$scope.loginGoogle = function() {
 var requestToken = '';
 var accessToken = '';
 var clientId = '1018908884240-futc1bfc681kl2jegi3a7nn1m28aem1o.apps.googleusercontent.com';
 var clientSecret = 'KRQGDwu_llvagUucKM9oLZ7I';
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $cordovaOauth.google(clientId, ['email']).then(function(result) {
                  $localStorage.accessToken = result.access_token;
                deferred.resolve(result.access_token);

            $http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=' + $localStorage.accessToken, {

                params: {
                    format: 'json'
                }
            }).then(function(result) {
 console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
 var id =result.data.id;
        
       deferred.resolve(result.data);
            }, function(error) {
                deferred.reject({
                    message: 'here was a problem getting your profile',
                    response: error
                });
            });


            }, function(error) {
                deferred.reject({
                    message: 'There was a problem signing in',
                    response: error
                });
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` to your index.html  file.
And Cordova plugins only runs on emulators or real devices. try [Ripple Emulator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc?hl=en) if you want to test it in a browser.

Credit to [Cordova plugins not working with ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25684371/cordova-plugins-not-working-with-ionic)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37569241/adding-facebook-login-to-ionic-app please find this let me know if anything

Comment: i am getting an error invalid request in iphone 5s ...invalid parameter value for request uri...my javascript origin is http://localhost and my redirect uri is http://localhost/callback

Comment: https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/google-plus-login-with-ionic-framework followed this tutorial worked well on andriod but not on ios, unable to get bday and gender from google api