# cordova is not defined in controller

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ionic and trying to donwload some file with cordova.
My error is:

```
ionic.bundle.js:26794 ReferenceError: cordova is not defined
at http://10.0.0.8:8100/js/controllers/settingsCtrl.js:9:22
at http://10.0.0.8:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:56230:19
```

my html:

```
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
```

and controller:

```
starter.controller('SettingsCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $window, $ionicPopup,$cordovaFileTransfer,$ionicPlatform) {

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function(){

    var url = "http://cdn.wall-pix.net/albums/art-space/00030109.jpg";
    var targetPath = cordova.file.documentsDirectory + "testImage.png";
```

what is missing?

Comment: The definition for Cordova looks like this: `<script src="cordova.js"></script>`, keep in mind that it does not work in the browser, are you by any chance testing your code in the browser?

Comment: Yes I am testing  it on chrome, do you have 2 flows to test it on chrome

Comment: See the steps that i wrote in this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37523038/adding-google-plus-login-to-ionic-app/37525072#37525072](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37523038/adding-google-plus-login-to-ionic-app/37525072#37525072) hope its useful.

Comment: Prepend your Cordova methods with the window object: `window.cordova.file.documentsDirectory`