# Adding Facebook login to ionic app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am newbie to a Angular and Ionic as well.

Tried the following tutorial:

https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-integrate-facebook-login-into-a-cordova-based-app/

Steps performed: 
1.In app browser is installed.

2. Included libraries.

   ```
   <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
   <script src="lib/ng-cordova-oauth/dist/ng-cordova-oauth.js"></script>
   <script src="cordova.js"></script>
   ```
3. Include code inside index.html before body closing tag:

   ```
   <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
       FB.init({
       appId      : 'MyappID',
       xfbml      : true,
       version    : 'v2.6'
     });
   };

     (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
   </script>
   ```
4. Following is my login.html :

   ```
    <button class="btn-margin-left button button-positive" ng-click="menuCtrl.fbLogin()">
     <i class="ion-social-facebook icon-size1 "></i>
    </button>
   ```
5. This is my controller :

   ```
   menuCtrl.fbLogin = function ($cordovaOauth,$http) {
       facebookLogin(window.cordovaOauth, window.http);
   }
   ```
6. This is my app.js :

   ```
   angular.module("cgsi",['ionic', 'ngCordova','ngCordovaOauth'])
     .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider, $httpProvider, $logProvider, $sceDelegateProvider,$cordovaOauth,$http) {
     window.cordovaOauth = $cordovaOauth;
     window.http = $http;
    });
   ```

I am getting error **Unknown provider $cordovaOauth**
Please let me know where i am going wrong?

Comment: remove **,'ngCordovaOauth'** from app.js

Comment: removed i am still getting the same error

Comment: have you included all libraries and cordova.js on the top

Comment: yes.. please check my updated code.

Comment: please refer this too https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth

Answer (score 1):

first of all you need to have account as facebook developer and generate one app for test,

> https://developers.facebook.com/

then create one cordova application and and set one button in UI side.

Then you need to install following plugin in your test-app.

> https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin

or

> https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4

please go through above plugin carefully because you need to add your app_id and app_name which you can find from developer-facebook account where you created your test app.

and then you need to go through related plugin documentation for getting facebook login code.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, i am facing issue while building the app via phonegap website. i am getting the error saying "Error - One of your plugins requires a parameter: APP_ID, APP_NAME "

Comment: I tried including this to my config.xml        <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" version="0.9.0">
        <param name="APP_ID" value="MyappId"/>
        <param name="APP_NAME" value="myappname"/>
    </gap:plugin>

Comment: in https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4 you can see at time of install plugin you need to give app-id and app-name with plugin add command please go throguh link and according to give details. If issue still persist please feedback,

Comment: yes i installed using variables still it gives me same error

Comment: follow some example then like http://excellencenodejsblog.com/cordova-ionic-facebook-login-mobile-app/ and http://www.clearlyinnovative.com/ionic-framework-facebook-login-with-parse and watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2je5D2xpmg for full intigration

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your controller has dependency injected or not, I hope you will get what my mean.

if still problem is same. use [Adding google plus login to ionic app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37523038/adding-google-plus-login-to-ionic-app/37525072)

And instead of google try facebook. after completion of installation you can add all other plugins that you want.

Comment: is it helpful to you?

Comment: Hi, i am facing issue while building the app via phonegap website. i am getting the error saying "Error - One of your plugins requires a parameter: APP_ID, APP_NAME "

Comment: I tried including this to my config.xml <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" version="0.9.0"> <param name="APP_ID" value="MyappId"/> <param name="APP_NAME" value="myappname"/> </gap:plugin>

Comment: I don't know which plugin you included but in genaral you can remove above  error using below command

cordova plugin add https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin.git --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"